# I am facing the error of DecisionTreeregressor object has no attribute n_features

Tags: machine-learning, regression, decision-trees

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/marks_prediction/app.py", line 150, in api
    output = sem3_prediction()
  File "/home/ubuntu/marks_prediction/app.py", line 18, in sem3_prediction
    result = loaded_model.predict(new_df)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sklearn/tree/_classes.py", line 419, in predict
    X = self._validate_X_predict(X, check_input)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sklearn/tree/_classes.py", line 387, in _validate_X_predict
    if self.n_features_ != n_features:
AttributeError: 'DecisionTreeRegressor' object has no attribute 'n_features_'
```

Comment: Hi@gaurav welcome to the data science SE. Could you please share the problem that you are trying to solve along with the code snippet that you wrote? This would to narrow down the problem

Comment: From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.n_features_): `DEPRECATED: The attribute n_features_ is deprecated in 1.0 and will be removed in 1.2. Use n_features_in_ instead.`

Answer (score 0):

The traceback indicates that you're using flask, and references `loaded_model`.  Given [@AlexSerraMarrugat's comment](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/114229/i-am-facing-the-error-of-decisiontreeregressor-object-has-no-attribute-n-feature#comment115400_114229), it seems likely that you trained the model in `sklearn>=1.0` (so it has an attribute `n_features_in_` but not `n_features_`) but your local copy has `sklearn<1.0` (so that the prediction code references `n_features_`).

This particular error aside, you should always use the same version of `sklearn` for training and prediction, to prevent unexpected results: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/model_persistence.html#security-maintainability-limitations